# ConTeXt from TeXLive 2021 says unknown script 'context.lua' or 'mtx-context.lua'

Tags: texlive, context

I installed texlive 2021 with ConTeXt on gentoo linux.

```
$ context --version
mtxrun          | unknown script 'context.lua' or 'mtx-context.lua'
```

`mtxrun --generate` doesn't fix anything.

After `export TEXMF=/usr/share/texmf-dist`,

```
$ context --version
resolvers       | globbing | confusing filename, name: 'custMatTransform.py', lower: 'custmattransform.py', already: 'CustMatTransform.py'
resolvers       | globbing | confusing filename, name: 'setCustomAnchor.py', lower: 'setcustomanchor.py', already: 'SetCustomAnchor.py'
resolvers       | globbing | confusing filename, name: 'widg_addLabel.py', lower: 'widg_addlabel.py', already: 'Widg_addLabel.py'
resolvers       | globbing | confusing filename, name: 'widg_addPolyOpt.py', lower: 'widg_addpolyopt.py', already: 'Widg_addPolyOpt.py'
resolvers       | globbing | confusing filename, name: 'widg_editBezier.py', lower: 'widg_editbezier.py', already: 'Widg_editBezier.py'
mtx-context     | ConTeXt Process Management 1.03
mtx-context     |
mtx-context     | main context file: /usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/context.mkiv
mtx-context     | current version: 2020.03.10 14:44
mtx-context     | main context file: /usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/context.mkxl
mtx-context     | current version: 2020.03.10 14:44
```

There should be no confusing filenames, but context seems to work as long as TEXMF is set to /usr/share/texmf-dist.

Comment: you don't say but `/usr/share/` suggests you installed the linux system packged texlive, not the upstream texlive from tug, as such any problems in the packaging or installation should be reported to the maintainer of the relevent gentoo package

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that texmfcnf.lua from texlive is outdated and broken.

Broken texmfcnf.lua breaks TexLive's ConTeXt.

Arch Linux texlive-core package has its own patched version of texmfcnf.lua.

TexLive needs to update texmfcnf.lua.

Comment: TeX Live's `texmfcnf.lua` is almost certainly not broken. However, what may be broken is Gentoo's `texmfcnf.lua`. I can run ConTeXt just fine on my system, so this almost certainly a distro packaging issue, not an issue with TeX Live itself.

Comment: @MaxChernoff Gentoo Linux uses upstream texmfcnf.lua. It seems upstream texmfcnf.lua can't handle TEXMFSYSCONFIG=/etc/texmf, TEXMFSYSVAR=/var/lib/texmf. TEXMFDIST=/usr/share/texmf-dist, and TEXMFOS=/usr/share.